# An unhandled win32 exception occurred in MSACCCESS.EXE

Tags: winapi, exception, ms-access, adp

I'm a web developer who's taken over an ADP project and needs help with the Windows and Access Environments.

I was coding in VBA in Access 2007, and would at times need to rebuild the project by importing forms, reports, and modules due to corruption issues.  I believe these issues were caused by run-time errors during coding.

I've upgraded to Access 2010 (Office Suite 2010 32-bit) on a Windows 7 Machine (64-bit).  The same (I believe) corruption issues in Access 2010 are invoking the following error:

After making changes in my project, I will save, exit, and attempt to open the project.  Access 2010 displays a message box "Access has stopped working".  I click "debug" and Windows attempts to open the Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger, with the following:

```
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in MSACCCESS.EXE [6648]
```

I exit out of Access 2010 and attempt to reopen the file and it throws the same exception.  I exit out again and attempt to open Access 2010 by itself, and Access attempts to create a Backup copy of the same file.  The process fails and throws the same exception.  I can open Access by holding the shift key while double-clicking, but when I attempt to rebuild the corrupted version I get the same error message as above.  So my rebuild is failing, and I'm stuck in 2010.  I can rebuild in 2007, but would like to fix this on this brand new machine which would be sweet to develop on.

Comment: Have you tried opening a fresh database and importing everything? Decompile? Compact and repair? Not necessarily in that order.

Comment: As stated in the problem description, I attempt to rebuild the project and import all forms, reports, and modules.  It gives me the same error.  I'm not sure where to check in the log files for more details.

Comment: Did you decompile? Compact and repair?

Comment: I was able to use the following information to decompile MSACCESS.EXE, which allows me to again rebuild the front-end in Access 2010, however the root issue occurs again (very frequently).  The root issue is not solved.  http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-do-i-decompile-database.html

Comment: I do not know what is causing your problem, but I have found that developing on an Access 2010 database without splitting it into front- and back-ends causes problems on my set-up.

Comment: The front-end is an ADP project.  The back-end is SQL Server.  Holding the shift key while opening Access, holding the shift key while opening the file, canceling the backup attempt each time it fires, and using the method in the link above at least allows me to continue to work. For now, almost every time I get a run-time error Access bombs and I'll need to re-open the project. I'm going to clear out any deprecated 2007 features and try to implement a error handler class module for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had inherited an Access 2003 database with a report that I had no involvement in designing.  I converted it to a `*.accdb` (MSAccess 2007) file and this error became a constant headache.  Sometimes it would work right after backing up and using the backup, and sometimes it didn't.

All the other queries and tables worked fine, except for the report.  The only thing special about that report was that it used a macro with a "SetValue" action of "[Page], 0".

After looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177384(v=office.12).aspx and seeing *"Note   This action will not be allowed if the database is not trusted."* at the top of the page, I went back to my database, changed my macro settings in the trust center to *"Enable all macros"*,  choose File, then Exit to go out of the database and it re-opened.